# How to disable a keymapping of a third-party addon

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I use MACHIN3tools addon in Blender. I am trying to permanently disable a key mapping using a Python script.

I tried this and it works.

```
bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps['Object Non-modal'].keymap_items['wm.call_menu_pie'].active=False
```

But when i restart, the keymaping is reactivated. Is there a way to disable this permanently using a script?

Comment: This might work, but I have not tested it: [link] (https://devtalk.blender.org/t/changing-keymap-on-startup/7153)

Comment: @relaxed, that code is supposed to be run when blender starts. That solution does not suit me.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand! Where is the difference between permanently and when blender starts?

Comment: @relaxed, i feel it is a bit overkill. In fact, i already have a bare bones addon with just register() which does these disabling functionalities. I was not satisfied with that approach and hence had posted the question. :) What i was looking for was a python snippet that does the exact same thing as Blender UI does when we disable keymapping on the Preferences.